# How can I restart NetHack, or at least replay the introduction?

Tags: nethack

I feel guilty for what I did: When I first started nethack I skipped the introduction and the instructions.

Now, I don't know how to play that stupid game. I only know how to move. Is there a way to restart the game from the beginning on ubuntu?

Comment: If you don't know what to do, see this http://alt.org/nethack/mirror/www.geocities.com/TimesSquare/Portal/2416/intro.html

Comment: ...but note that the guide linked by @TheIdiotGamer is written for a fairly old version of NetHack (v3.1; current is v3.4.3), and some of the details are no longer true (for example, Elf is no longer a class). The [official guidebook](http://www.nethack.org/v343/Guidebook.html) is more accurate, but not as detailed. There's also a more up-to-date tutorial on [StrategyWiki](http://strategywiki.org/wiki/NetHack). And, of course, there's always the [NetHack Wiki](http://nethackwiki.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this will work, but try deleting or renaming the file `.nethackrc` in your home directory. This file contains all your settings so if you've made a extensive changes to them you may just want to rename it and then put it back after you've read the introduction.

Comment: thank you, actually it was call nethack.tty I found it in /etc/nethack.